# Multiplicar a quantidade de elementos de duas tabelas diferentes

Tags: sql, postgresql

Possuo duas tabelas: `pessoas` e `carros`.

Gostaria de pegar o número de elementos de ambas as tabelas, e multiplicá-los.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Acho que isso é o que você quer:

```
SELECT a.c * b.d AS produto
FROM (SELECT COUNT(*) AS c FROM pessoas) a,
     (SELECT COUNT(*) AS d FROM carros) b
```

Answer (score 2):

```
select 
    (select count(*) from pessoas) *
    (select count(*) from carros)
```