# Subtrair somas de campos em em duas tabelas distintas

Tags: mysql, sql

Preciso somar o valor de uma coluna no SQL, então fica assim:

```
SELECT SUM(qtdsaco) FROM armazem
```

Esse código funciona. Agora preciso somar o valor da outra tabela, aí fica assim:

```
SELECT SUM(qtdsaco) FROM armazem2
```

Então precisava pegar o resultado das duas e subtrair. Como faço?

Comment: Você quer somar tudo das duas e subtrair um do outro?

Comment: Sim quero somar tudo de uma coluna e tudo de outra e subtrair, o valor da coluna qtdsaco do armazem - o valor qtdsaco armazem2 dois e pegar o resultado

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você terá que ver qual tabela vem primeiro e fazer desta forma jogando o valor em um `total`:

```
SELECT (SUM(qtdsaco) - (SELECT SUM(qtdsaco) FROM armazem2)) total FROM armazem
```

Comment: Eu tenho que criar um campo em uma das duas tabelas com nome de total para lançar o valor lá dentro o valor do resultado vc fala ?

Comment: não, se você colocar desta forma, seu resultado virá com uma coluna já nomeada como `total`.

Comment: Obrigado por responder deu certo obrigado

Comment: @checkmate se precisar, dê um grito aqui. Lembrando que existe várias formas de resolver seu problema. Esta aqui seria apenas 1.

Comment: Brigado patraoo

Answer (score 4):

O `SELECT` serve para selecionar informações de qualquer forma. Nem precisa ser do banco de dados. Ele pode selecionar dados se sub-expressões SQL, incluindo outros `SELECT`s. Então pode fazer cada um deles como sub-expressão e a substração das duas no `SELECT` principal.

```
SELECT (SELECT SUM(qtdsaco) FROM armazem) - (SELECT SUM(qtdsaco) FROM armazem2)
```

Veja [funcionando no **SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a3346/1). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/SQL/Select/SumDiff.sql).

Obviamente pode obter o mesmo resultado com variações de expressão SQL. Eu achei essa mais adequada porque é simples e demonstra com clareza a intenção. Se tivesse outros requisitos eu optaria por outra forma. Segui o que a pergunta pedia *ipsis litteris*.

Comment: deu esse erro ` #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ')
LIMIT 0, 25' at line 1 `

Comment: Tem coisas aí no erro que não constam na sua pergunta. Se você colocou um `LIMI` deveria estar na descrição do problema. Agora tem respostas dadas em cima do que perguntou e o problema era diferente do que estava descrito. Ficou um problema. Não garanto, mas se editar a pergunta colocando de fato o que deseja, talvez dê para salvar a pergunta.

Comment: Mestre deu certo aqui queria te pontuar vc respondeu muito rapido e não consigo pq ainda não tenho 15 pontos mas quando tiver irei te pontuar aqui obrigado por responder

Answer (score 3):

Me baseando [nesta outra resposta minha](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/146916/132), eu faria assim:

```
SELECT a.c - b.d AS qtdsaco
FROM (SELECT SUM(qtdsaco) AS c FROM armazem) a,
     (SELECT SUM(qtdsaco) AS d FROM armazem2) b
```

Comment: Obrigado por responder amigo

Answer (score 2):

Faça uso de `subselects`:

```
select (SELECT SUM(qtdsaco) FROM armazem) - (SELECT SUM(qtdsaco) FROM armazem2)
```

Answer (score 1):

Você pode fazer um JOIN da seguinte forma.

```
declare @armazem table(qtdsaco int)
declare @armazem2 table( qtdsaco int)
insert into @armazem values(112),(3),(432),(22),(1),(5),(4),(3),(2)
insert into @armazem2 values(1),(2),(3),(4),(6),(5),(4),(3),(2)

select SUM(a1.qtdsaco) - SUM(a2.qtdsaco) total
from @armazem a1
join  @armazem2 a2 on 1 = 1
```

> Obs; como não foi especificado o banco de dados, isso foi feito em sql
>   server.

Comment: Obrigado por responder amigo